# XCODE / iOS: setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Destination

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

### Issue:

I'm attempting to navigate from my  `Login View Controller Scene` to `iPad Start Menu Scene` however I'm getting an error stating:

> setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key

and the app crashes. I've attempted looking through my connections in Interface Builder for any issues as well as inspecting the source code of my `Main.storyboard` for any (obvious) issues.

I'm really not sure what is causing this issue in this instance however any suggestions are truly appreciated.

### Source:

https://github.com/androiddeveloperfl/SA3

### Error Snippet:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Destination.'

Comment: You should double check your connections in Interface Builder. The most obvious case is a "dangling" reference to an iboutlet which your view controller class no longer implements.

Comment: whats your contains man its overall 78 MB bro..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error says **[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Destination.**, you were created the **Destination** in your xib , after that you deleted in your xib but not in `Connection Inspector`. select File's Owner and click on the "Connection Inspector" (upper right arrow), to see all outlets at once.
Look for `!`s which indicates a missing outlet.if you want this just remove the connection and add again once.problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If this error shows for view controller when you navigate from one to another.
Steps:

1. Go to project target
2. In project target select "Build Phases"
3. In "Build Phases" select "Compile Sources"
4. In "Compile Sources" add your view controller i.e ".m " file
5. Build your project and run